# Best practice for multiple search-items and pagination in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, pagination, twig

I have to deal with a search form with deals with multiple input-fiels and pagination in Symfony2.

Therefore I have created a route

```
/**
  * @Route("/project/{page}/{search}", defaults={"page" = 1, "search" = "all", })
  **/
```

search without content is per default "all" - otherwise it is an array. Page contains the # of page the user is currently displaying.

The controller:

```
public function showAll($page, $search, Request $request)
{
    if ($search != 'all') {
        $search = unserialize($search);
        if(count($search)) {
            foreach ($search as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == 'name') {
                    $searchProject->setName($value);
                }
                .....
            }
        }
    }
    $searchForm = $this->createForm(new ProjectSearchType(), $searchProject);
    $searchForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($searchForm->isSubmitted()) {
        $name = $searchForm["name"]->getData();
        $id = $searchForm["id"]->getData();
        $search = array('name' => $name, 'id' => $id);
    }

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Project');
    if ($search == 'all') {
        $projectResult = $repository->getAllActiveEntries($page, $itemsPerPage);
    }
    else {
        $projectResult = $repository->getAllActiveEntries($page, $itemsPerPage, $search);
    }

    $projectTable = $projectResult["query"];
    $totalCount = $projectResult["total"];

    $pagination = new \lib\Pagination($page, $totalCount, $itemsPerPage);
    $pageList = $pagination->getPagesList();
    $route_params = $request->attributes->get('_route_params');
    $route_params["search"] = serialize($search);

    return $this->render(
        'project/overview.html.twig',
        array(
            'searchForm' => $searchForm->createView(),
            'table' => $projectTable,
            'pagination' => $pageList,
            'currentPage' => $page,
            'currentFilters' => $route_params,
            'lastPage' => $pagination->getTotalPages(),
            'totalcount' => $totalCount,
            'paginationPath' => $route,
            'showAlwaysFirstAndLast' => true
        )
    );
```

DB-Jobs:

```
class ProjektRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getAllActiveEntries($page, $rowsPerPage, $search=array())
    {
        $startFromEntry = ($page-1)*$rowsPerPage;

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('project');
        if((count($search)) && (is_array($search))) {
            foreach ($search as $key => $value) {
                if ($value != '') {
                    $qb->andWhere('project.' . $key . ' LIKE :' . $key)
                        ->setParameter($key, $value);
                }
            }
        }

        $q = $qb;

        $countQuery = $q;
        $totalCount = $countQuery->select('COUNT(project)')
            ->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

        $selectQuery = $q;
        $selectResult = $selectQuery->select(array('project'))
            ->setFirstResult($startFromEntry)
            ->setMaxResults($rowsPerPage)
            ->getQuery()->getResult();

        return array(
            'total' => $totalCount,
            'query' => $selectResult
        );
    }
}
```

The page containing the overview includes the twig-part which handles the pagination:

```
{#// Pageination#}
{% block body %}
    <div class="pagination" id="pagination" align="center">
        {% spaceless %}
            {% if lastPage > 1 %}

                {# the number of first and last pages to be displayed #}
                {% set extremePagesLimit = 3 %}

                {# the number of pages that are displayed around the active page #}
                {% set nearbyPagesLimit = 2 %}

                {#<pre>#}
                    {{ dump(currentFilters) }}
                    {#{{ dump(app.request.attributes) }}#}
                    {#{{ dump(app.request.attributes.get('_route_params')) }}#}
                {#</pre>#}

                <div class="pagination">
                    {% if currentPage > 1 %}
                        <a href="{{ path(paginationPath, currentFilters|merge({page: currentPage-1})) }}">Previous</a>&nbsp;

                        {% for i in range(1, extremePagesLimit) if ( i < currentPage - nearbyPagesLimit ) %}
                            <a href="{{ path(paginationPath, currentFilters|merge({page: i})) }}">{{ i }}</a>&nbsp;
                        {% endfor %}

                        {% if extremePagesLimit + 1 < currentPage - nearbyPagesLimit %}
                            <span class="sep-dots">...</span>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% for i in range(currentPage-nearbyPagesLimit, currentPage-1) if ( i > 0 ) %}
                            <a href="{{ path(paginationPath, currentFilters|merge({page: i})) }}">{{ i }}</a>&nbsp;
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% elseif showAlwaysFirstAndLast %}
                        <span id="disabled">Previous</span>&nbsp;
                    {% endif %}

                    <a id="currentPage"
                       href="{{ path(paginationPath, currentFilters|merge({ page: currentPage })) }}"
                            >{{ currentPage }}</a>&nbsp;

                    {% if currentPage < lastPage %}
                        {% for i in range(currentPage+1, currentPage + nearbyPagesLimit) if ( i <= lastPage ) %}
                            <a href="{{ path(paginationPath, currentFilters|merge({page: i})) }}">{{ i }}</a>&nbsp;
                        {% endfor %}

                        {% if  (lastPage - extremePagesLimit) > (currentPage + nearbyPagesLimit) %}
                            <span class="sep-dots">...</span>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% for i in range(lastPage - extremePagesLimit+1, lastPage) if ( i > currentPage + nearbyPagesLimit ) %}
                            <a href="{{ path(paginationPath, currentFilters|merge({page: i})) }}">{{ i }}</a>&nbsp;
                        {% endfor %}

                        <a href="{{ path(paginationPath, currentFilters|merge({page: currentPage+1})) }}">Next</a>&nbsp;
                    {% elseif showAlwaysFirstAndLast %}
                        <span id="disabled">Next</span>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endspaceless %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I do not really feel comfortable regarding the serialize-Workaround for the search-Array. Is there a better way? Or a better practice?

Comment: i suggest you to take a look at the [LexikFormFilterBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle) that enable filter based on a form and i would suggest the [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) also for manage the pagination. You can see an example of the use of this two bundle in conjunction [here](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/working-with-other-bundles.md#i-knp-paginator-example). Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Thank you for the hints - I also had a look at other bundles and finally found APYDataGridBundle which solves all my problems with very litte effort. Here I am able to use pagination, search and I do not have to write the table in twig or the db-querys in doctrine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the hints you gave me - I also had a look at other bundles and finally found APYDataGridBundle which solves all my problems with very litte effort. Here I am able to use pagination, search and I do not have to write the table in twig or the db-querys in doctrine.